# How to fix "Gem::InvalidSpecificationException" error after breaking a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gem-bundler

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "nba_schedule"
  spec.version       = NBA_Schedule::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["TylerP33"]
  spec.email         = ["tyler3321@gmail.com"]

  spec.summary       = %q{TODO: Write a short summary, because RubyGems 
  requires one.}
  spec.description   = %q{TODO: Write a longer description or delete this 
  line.}
  spec.homepage      = "TODO: Put your gem's website or public repo URL 
  here."
  spec.license       = "MIT"
```

So in the above .gemspec folder, I had changed my spec.version from `NbaSchedule::VERSION` to `NBA_Schedule::Version`, which is what you see below (it was just too ugly).

Because `NbaSchedule` was used at the time of gem creation (used a command to stub out all the necessary gem files I would need to start one from scratch), it is giving me a lot of grief for changing it and I can't figure out why.  I have covered all the dependencies by changing them as needed.

Am I missing something here?

```
/home/TylerP/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-
1.16.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:65:in `rescue in validate': The 
gemspec at /mnt/c/Users/tyler/Desktop/nba_schedule/nba_schedule.gemspec is 
not valid. Please fix this gemspec. (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
The validation error was '"FIXME" or "TODO" is not a description'
```

My error is above.

I am fairly new to coding, period.  So I understand I may be missing something glaring but I would love to know why it is breaking if everything is cohesive and changed over.

Comment: The error is telling you specifically what the problem is. `The validation error was '"FIXME" or "TODO" is not a description'`.

Comment: Ah.... Those are default strings that are put into the .gemspec file to remind you to do fill them in as needed.  My bad!  And thank you!